# database question - Thrashing - What Is?

Tags: terminology

Whats Thrashing?
Ive heard it mentioned a few times at work and dont want to ask...
Probably a stupid question - any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Reading through those pages :

- [MySQL + LARGE innodb = thrashing HDD](http://bytes.com/topic/mysql/answers/586190-mysql-large-innodb-thrashing-hdd)
- [Reduce thrashing or poor system performance](http://www.cryer.co.uk/brian/oracle/tuning_reduce_thrashing.htm)

I arrived to that one : [Disk Thrashing](http://www.cryer.co.uk/glossary/d/disk_thrashing.htm), which states *(quoting)*

> On a system with Virtual Memory, pages
>   of memory are read from and written to
>   the swap file as necessary. 
> Disk
>   Thrashing is when there is excessive
>   paging, specifically when the I/O
>   system is busy paging memory but the
>   CPU is not fully utilized - generally
>   if the system is unresponsive (i.e.
>   slow) and there is lots of disk
>   activity then the system is likely to
>   be thrashing.

And, of course, you might want to take a look on the [Thrash (computer science)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thrash_%28computer_science%29) page on wikipedia ;-)

Answer (score 4):

Thraching is where a process consumes all available resources without achieving anything useful.  Examples are endless loops or code that retries a failed command endlessly.

Answer (score 1):

lmgify?
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thrash_%28computer_science%29